# Is it possible to store calculated fields in a List?

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been looking for related information around but I can't seem to find a suitable one.

Is there any method where by I can call my method to save it in the list?
I have tried looping the list but it does not work.

Say for example I want to call this method and store it in the List, with the qsnID++ every time its a new Model.Test

```
public static double FindAvgScore(double[,] testArray)
    {
        int k = 2;

        double max = FindMax(testArray);
        double min = FindMin(testArray);
        double midPoint = (max - min) / k;
        double avg = min + midPoint;

        return avg;
    }
```

The codes I have below is hard coded to test the passing of data.
Eventually, I want to store **calculated fields** like the return value for my FindAvgScore method in the List.

```
  List<Model.Test> lstItems = new List<Model.Test>()
                {
                    new Model.Test() { qsnID =1011, binOne =100 },
                    new Model.Test() { qsnID =1012, binOne =20 }

                };
```

The List is then passed to a POST method where I used javascript to display it on a table. The hard coded values are able to be displayed in a row.

Also, how do I go about displaying an array of integers in a table?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I didn't understand what is actually the question... What do you want to store in a list? Seems like you know how to add values to a list

Comment: Can you elaborate more and how you are looping through the list.

Comment: @Galid Green: I want to store the calculated value in my method FindAvgScore instead of hard coded data. I've been trying to call the method in my list but it's not working. Is it even possible for lists to call methods?

Comment: @Vivek: I've tried doing it, but i can't seem to get the loop to work with a list. I'm not to sure myself if Lists can be looped to store method values

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you are trying to pass that `List<Model.Test>` to a view of some sort, and you want to pass the Maximum, Minimum, MidPoint, and Average to the view as well.

Instead of trying to store it within a `List<T>`, I would recommend creating a new object that wraps all of the data (called `ViewModel` below).

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model.Test> Items { get; set; }
    public double Max => FindMax(this.Items);
    public double Min => FindMin(this.Items);
    public double MidPoint => (this.Max / this.Min) / 2;
    public double Average => this.Min + this.MidPoint;
}
```

Using this `ViewModel` class, you abstract the calculation of the Min/Max/MidPoint/Average to the class that cares about it.

---

More clarification on how this works in ASP.NET MVC.

**Model** (`Test.cs`)

```
public class Test
{
    public int qsnId { get; set; }
    public int binOne { get; set; }
    // Other properties related to the object
}
```

**ViewModel** (`ViewModel.cs`)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model.Test> Items { get; set; }
    public double Max => FindMax(this.Items);
    public double Min => FindMin(this.Items);
    public double MidPoint => (this.Max / this.Min) / 2;
    public double Average => this.Min + this.MidPoint;
}
```

**Controller** (`HomeController.cs`)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Items = GetItems(); // This retrieves the items from wherever you get them from

        return new View(vm);
    }
}
```

**View** (`Index.cshtml`)

```
@model ViewModel

<h2>Index View</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Max: @Model.Max</li>
    <li>Min: @Model.Min</li>
    <li>MidPoint: @Model.MidPoint</li>
    <li>Average: @Model.Average</li>
</ul>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>QSN Id</th>
            <th>Bin One</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.qsnId</td>
                <td>@item.binOne</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Forgive me if any of this doesn't compile, it was all typed from memory. This should get you going though!

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I should go about adding these codes and how I should call the model? I'm rather new to MVC. Thanks!

Comment: Tony Morris: Thank you very much for the extended codes! Appreciated! I'm not sure why I can't seem to have"GetItems()" working in my controller. Is it because I'm using ASP.NET Core?

Also, for the ViewModel class, "public double Min => FindMin(this.Items);" and FindMax "Does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @MaryLim: you have to write the `GetItems` method yourself. Also you need to write the `FindMin` and `FindMax` methods in the `ViewModel` class. If this answer has answered your initial question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Write the FindMin and FindMax methods in the ViewModel class? correct me if I'm wrong but from what I know about MVC so far, business ideas belong in the controller. Does it affect the codes?